# How do I properly set the FocusTraversalPolicy of a JFrame instance in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, components, focus

I've played with this for probably a combined total of a couple hours now and I cannot figure out how to properly set the FocusTraversalPolicy of a JFrame. I've tried creating a custom traversal policy as well, unsuccessfully. When the JFrame is created, the correct field is focused by default but tab and shift-tab do not do anything at all.

This is what the form looks like:

[image: Add Party JFrame Form]

This is my code to instantiate the form:

```
AddParty addPartyWindow = new AddParty(this, waitlist, times);
addPartyWindow.setFocusCycleRoot(true);
addPartyWindow.setFocusTraversalPolicy(new LayoutFocusTraversalPolicy());
addPartyWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
addPartyWindow.setVisible(true);
addPartyWindow.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    try {
        renderPartyTable(waitlist.getGroup(times.get(0)));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LaserTagWaitlist.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        print(ex.getMessage());
    }
    }
});
print("AddParty is Focus Cycle Root: " + addPartyWindow.isFocusCycleRoot());
print("AddParty Focus Traversal Policy set: " + addPartyWindow.isFocusTraversalPolicySet());
print("AddParty Focus Traversal Policy: " + addPartyWindow.getFocusTraversalPolicy());
print("Add party is Focus Traversal Policy Provider: " + addPartyWindow.isFocusTraversalPolicyProvider());
print("Opened AddParty window");
```

This is the output from the print calls:

```
[02:41:13.369] AddParty is Focus Cycle Root: true
[02:41:13.369] AddParty Focus Traversal Policy set: true
[02:41:13.370] AddParty Focus Traversal Policy: javax.swing.LayoutFocusTraversalPolicy@7c7752bc
[02:41:13.370] Add party is Focus Traversal Policy Provider: true
[02:41:13.370] Opened AddParty window
```

Comment: Just curious, why do you need your own FocusTraversalPolicy? In my experience, Swing gets it right 99.9% of the times.

Comment: I don't - that's why I'm trying to use LayoutFocusTraversalPolicy. I just need one that goes from top to bottom. Is there a different way to accomplish this? Maybe I'm missing something simple.

Comment: What about removing it altogether? I have been programming Swing for quite a few years and never had to do this. Remove the setFocus* methods and see how it works out for you. If it fails, post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.